# Invoke native Android dialer, ignoring all other broadcast receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have multiple apps.  When I make a call from one, I don't want any of the others (if on the phone, which may or may not be) to intercept it.  When doing this

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, phoneNumber);
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

is there a flag I can send to say "ignore all BroadcastReceivers except the native dialler"?

(I presume I could add data to the intent like, dialIntent.putExtra("cameFromMyApp", "ignoreMe") and check for that in all my receivers and that, if there were none, the Android dialler would just ignore the extra data, but a flag to do this would be much simpler.)

Comment: @RvdK the CALL Intent isn't a broadcast, it starts an activity.

Comment: d0h sorry misread. Than the answer would be, set the target :)

Comment: @David Wasser If the CALL isn't what triggers the broadcast, would the call still be broadcast by the phone even when targeted?

Comment: Hopefully my answer will help explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing some things here (activity `Intent` and broadcast `Intent`). Let me try to help.

When you do:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, phoneNumber);
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

this causes Android to look for available `Activity`s that have advertised that they can handle `ACTION_CALL`. The standard Android dialer is one of these, but there may also be others installed on the phone. If there is only one, that Activity is started. If there is more than one, then the user is shown a list of possible Activities and the user can select the one he wants to use. You have no control over this behaviour if the `Intent` you send is an **implicit** Intent (ie: does not have a component specified).

Let's now assume that the standard Android dialer application has been chosen. It sends an ordered broadcast using `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. This broadcast will be sent, in order, to all `BroadcastReceiver`s that have registered for this broadcast. This gives these components the opportunity to modify the number, dial the number or block the call. You have no control over this behaviour either.

To force the standard Android dialer to be used, you would need to use an **explicit** Intent (ie: specify the component name). The problem is that every manufacturer and/or mobile operator can provide a custom dialer which is used instead of the standard Android dialer, so this won't work on all phones.

However, as I said earlier, even if you could be sure that the standard Android dialer would be launched, it will still send the ordered broadcast allowing other components to modify, dial, or block the call.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. It seems like neither of my original ideas will work.  Is there a different way I can do what I want?

Comment: Please explain exactly what it is you want to do. What is the problem if there are other apps installed that want to modify or block the outgoing call?

Comment: It's possible for some of my apps to start calls that the other apps might intercept; when the call is initiated from one of my apps, I don't want those apps to intercept the call (though otherwise, they should).

Comment: When one of your apps is initiating a call and you don't want your other apps to intercept then you probably need to store the current date/time and the current calling number in a shared preference that is readable by all of your apps. They could then read the preference, compare the number, see if the date time is not too long ago (10 seconds? 5 seconds?) and use that information to determine whether or not to intercept the call.

Comment: Good idea, but it looks like Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated in the latest version of Android; while this works fine on my ZTE, it fails on my Nexus. :(

Comment: Hmmm. **Deprecated** doesn't mean that it no longer works. **Deprecated** just means that it may no longer work **in the future** and that you shouldn't rely on it **in the future**. So the fact that it fails on your Nexus is probably due to other reasons.

Comment: Did you set `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`? You must set that otherwise 2 applications (which run in different processes) won't see changes in the shared preferences.

Comment: If the shared prefs idea doesn't work, you will need to create a generic server that stores the data. Each of your applications will need to contact the generic server to tell it that it is making a call currently, or to ask if another of your apps is making a call currently. Unfortunately this means that you will need to package the server in a separate APK and your users will need to install both the generic server APK and your app's APK.

Comment: As a workaround to this problem you could deliver a server in each APK (one server for each app), and when the app wants to contact the server, it first tries to contact an existing server. If none is available, it starts its own. This would be a more complicated setup, but is easier for users. To communicate with the server you will need to send **implicit Intents** (ie: ACTION set, but component names not set) because each server will have a different package name. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. We'll figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

if you find out the package name of your desired native dialler you can call that particular dialler only and pass the needed intent extras. here's some untested code to help illustrate what i mean:

```
    String number = "111-333-222-4";

    String uri = "tel:" + number.trim() ;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setPackage("com.mydialler.package.name");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Be aware different phone carriers add their own diallers so they will have their own package names.

EDIT - I realised the code above assumed you have access to the class so edited the code with a different approach to set the  package name. Note you can also use this approach to get a launch intent and tweak the intent data afterwards:

```
   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mydialler.package");
```

Comment: Hey, that's my phone number! Also my password and national ID number.

Comment: So there isn't a generic sort of com.android.phone.class I can target that will always work?  Otherwise this seems exactly what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a generic android phone class, the intent system was made to be generic so you can fire an intent with a certain action and any app that has that filter will be able to pick it up. If you want to target specific diallers you'll have to get a list of the diallers you want to target and then check to see if they're installed on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + url));
    intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster");

    startActivity(intent);
```